# Asp.Net Identity sample - Where injected for account controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

When I create asp.net identity with individual account, I notice in account controller construct method, there are 2 parameters.

```
        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }
```

I want to know when they have been injected? because I havent seen any DI tools.

Thanks

Comment: When I remove them , it still works for register and login function.